Memory exhausted error when opening LaTeX file in Emacs with custom configuration
I'm encountering a memory exhaustion error when trying to open a LaTeX file in Emacs with a custom configuration. Here is the relevant part of my local .dir-locals.el configuration:
((latex-mode . ((eval . (progn
                          ;; Disable the welcome screen
                          (setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

                          ;; Function to maximize the window
                          (defun maximize-frame ()
                            "Maximize the current frame"
                            (interactive)
                            (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized))

                          ;; Maximize the frame when opening a LaTeX file
                          (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'maximize-frame)

                          ;; Debug message
                          (message "LaTeX mode: Welcome screen disabled and window maximized"))))))

Whenever I try to open Emacs with emacs --debug-init main.tex, I get the following error:
File mode specification error: (error Memory exhausted--use C-x s then exit and restart Emacs)
<left-fringe> <drag-mouse-1> is undefined

Steps to Reproduce

Add the above configuration to the local .dir-locals.el file
Create a minimal LaTeX file (main.tex):
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello, World!

\end{document}


Open Emacs with the command: emacs --debug-init main.tex.

Environment

Emacs version: 29.4
Operating System: Windows 10

